# decoding a .shs file that contains chinese

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I've recently come across this .shs file that should contain chinese characters. The original document is written in 2005. When I opened the .shs file in notepad, it contained a mass amount of gibberish as well as a bunch of what seems to be hex numbers.

here is an example:

\'ca\'c7\'cb\'ef\'d7\'d3\'a3\'ac\'c8\'e7\'b9\'fb\'b5\'b1\'d5\'e6\'b5\'c4\'bb\'b0\'d5\'e2\'d2\'bb\'b0\'ef\'d7\'d3\'b6\'bc\'bf\'ec\'d3\'d0\'cb\'ef\'d7\'d3\'b5\'c4\'d0\'fe\'cb\'ef\'d7\'d3\'c1\'cb\'a3\'ac\'d3\'ae\'c1\'cb\'c7\'ae\'b5\'bd\'b4\'a6\'c2\'f2

How might I go about translating this document back into Chinese?

Answer (score 0):

Scrap files are no longer supported by Windows/Office. Microsoft dropped support in Vista / Windows 7 for security reasons.

You might be lucky and still be able to get an old version of Windows XP / Office in an isolated environment (e.g. an offline VM) where you can still open the Scrap file. In fact, it might be sufficient if you have Windows XP and WordPad. To open the file in WordPad, start WordPad and drag the Scrap file into the application window. If an icon appears in WordPad instead of the file's text content, right-click the icon and select "Package Object/Edit Package" to view the scrap file's contents.

And please be aware that scrap files may contain malware. If you are not sure about the source of the file, it's probably best to not open it.